# Execute any X file in a directory every X seconds

Tags: c, windows

I have this code in C. It executes a batch file every 8 seconds continuously.

```
int main ()
{
    for (;;)
        {
        system ("start C:\\Execute\\xxx.bat");
        Sleep(8000);
        }
}
```

How can I do to execute any .bat file? I mean, whichever .bat file I insert inside C:\Execute must be executed, until I delete the file. If there is nothing inside, it won't do nothing, until I insert another .bat file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

metacode:

- forever

  - read content of directory (depending on your operating system, f.e. DosFindFirst)
  - for each content which is a .bat (and not empty)

    - call system
  - sleep (inside or out side the for each depending on your needs)

Comment: Thank you. I can't get it with findfirst, is there another way?

Comment: @Isdera I would use the opendir() family ("man opendir" and corresponding functions)